# Why do developers implement OAuth to use Google API?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

Currently, I working on the web application that uses Youtube API. My app just gets the information of video and displays it on my website. It does not do any fancy stuff such as updating video information. I am going to add some functionalities later, but this is what I did so far.

Then, I was wondering why can't I paste api key in the url and request information on my server side instead of using complicated OAuth (NOT the client side because users can see my api key). Since I use Codeigniter, and the google api library for it is deprecated, I want avoid using it now.

Could you tell me why we have to implement OAuth when we use Google API?

Comment: _I was wondering why can't I paste api key in the url and request information on my server side instead of using complicated OAuth_ - can you explain better?

Comment: _Why do developers implement OAuth to use Google API?_ -  For authentication and authorization.

Comment: Now, I am just using youtube api without OAuth. For example, I am using it like
file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key={my_api_key}&id={video_id}')
Is this a bad way to use Youtube API?

Answer (score 1):

Not all of the YouTube methods require authentication some of them can be accessed using a public API key because they return public data.

> I was wondering why can't I paste api key in the url and request
>   information on my server:

here are two statements showing that working.

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
>
> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&chart=mostPopular&key={YOUR_API_KEY}